# Component of Hilbert scheme of large degree rational curves in Fano such that no curve in the component is ample

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective Fano variety of dimension $n$ with Picard number one. Assume that the tangent bundle of $X$ is not nef. We say a rational curve $C \subset X$ is ample if $TX\vert_C$ is ample.

Question: Is it always possible to find a component of the Hilbert scheme of rational curves in $X$ of arbitrary large degree ( at least $2n$), such that no curve through a general point is ample but free?

Comment: The established name for a rational curve on which the restriction of $TX$ is ample is a "very free" rational curve (going back to papers of Koll'ar, Miyaoka and Mori).  Also, what do you mean when you say that "no curve through a general point is ample but free"?  Do you mean that you want a curve through a general point to be free (automatic in characteristic zero) yet not very free?

Comment: Yes. I am asking whether, a general curve of large degree $(\ge 2n)$, through a general point is free but not very free.

Comment: There do exist examples of Fano manifolds of Picard rank one and with $TX$ not nef such that for arbitrarily positive degree there is an irreducible component of the Hilbert scheme parameterizing free curves (that sweep out the Fano manifold) which are not very free.  If you allow your curves to be "multiple covers", then I proved this happens for all smooth cubic threefolds in my thesis.  You can also look at Castravet's thesis for other examples.

Comment: Is it always true for some degree $ \ge2n$ ? Multiple covers of given $d$-degree curve have dimension $2m -2$, degree of the branch locus.  Thus the total dimension of such curves will be $d + 2m -4$. On the other hand, the degree of such curves is $dm$ which has dimension $dm-2$. Then how the multiples covers will form a component ? May be I am missing something. Could you please specify the page number of your thesis where I can find this ?

Comment: The covers will form a component if the Fano index equals $2$ so that $dm$ equals $2m$.  This is what happens for cubic threefolds, quartic fourfolds, etc.

Comment: In general, will we always have a family of rational curve of degree $dm$  for any $m$, where $d$ is the minimal degree of dimension $d+2m-4$ consisting of free irreducible rational curves ((that sweep out the Fano manifold) ?

Comment: I am not certain what you are asking.

Comment: I guess $m-$ degree covers of the minimal rational curves, will give a family of free curves of dimension $d+2m-4$ and also this family cover the manifold.  If  I'm making any mistake please correct me.

Comment: You are not making any mistakes.  So that equals the expected dimension, $md-2$, if $2m + (d-2)$ equals $dm$, i.e., if $d$ equals $2$.  In other words, if the Fano index equals $2$, the multiple covers of "lines" (having anticanonical degree $d=2$) give examples, e.g., cubic threefolds, quartic fourfolds, etc.  If the Fano index equals $1$, the multiple covers of "conics" give examples.

Comment: I am not saying such family forms a component but a subvariety of a component which also covers the manifold.

Comment: Does it make sense ?

Comment: It makes sense, but in the cases in my comment, the subvariety is an entire irreducible component.

Comment: Yes.  I understood that.